# How do I use a C# generated RSA public key in Android?

Tags: c#, android, .net, encryption, rsa

I want to ensure message privacy between an Android app and C# ASP.NET server, in a situation where HTTPS can't be assumed to be available.

I want to use RSA to encrypt a symmetric key which is transferred from the Android device when it first contacts the server.

The RSA key pair has been generated on the server and the private key is held on the server.
The key pair was generated in C# using:

```
// Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
// Ensure that the key doesn't get persisted
rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
RSAParameters parameters = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
string modulus = Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.Modulus);
string exponent = Convert.ToBase64String(parameters.Exponent);
string xmlKeys = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
```

Attempting to embed the public key by hard-coding (copying from Visual Studio to Eclipse) doesn't work. The code throws an org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException: input too large for RSA cipher on the rsaCipher.doFinal() method call.

```
// Generate a new AES key
byte[] key = null;
try {
    KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keygen.init(128);            
    key = keygen.generateKey().getEncoded();
}
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {}

// Set up modulus and exponent
String mod = "qgx5606ADkXRxndzurIRa5GDxzDYg5Xajeym7I8BXG1HBSzaaGmX+rjQfZK1h4JtQU+Xaowsc81mgJU8+gwneQa56r1bl6/5jFue4FsdXKfpau5az8rY2SAHKcOeyHAOsT9ZqcNa1x6cL/jl9P3cBtOzMk51Hk/w6VNoQ5JJo/0m/eAJzlhVKr2xbOYFhd0xp3qUgRuK8TN4TsSvfc+R1LOWc8+3H22Zj3vhBxSqSgeXxdxi7ThiGiAl6HUwMf8ph7FHNJvoUQq+QPL6dx77pu6xVFiHv1JOfpbKcOubn0VSPLYKY3QPKCzNMYQ6pxUDqzpGtydHR1xaX5K0FGTraw==";

String ex = "AQAB";
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(Base64.decode(mod, Base64.DEFAULT));
BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(Base64.decode(ex, Base64.DEFAULT));

// Encrypt the AES key
PublicKey pubKey;
byte[] cipherData;
try {
    pubKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpe(modulus, exponent));
    Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");     
    rsaCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
    // The following line fails with:
    // org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException
    cipherData = rsaCipher.doFinal(key);     
}
catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {}
catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {}
catch (InvalidKeyException e) {}
catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {}
catch (BadPaddingException e) {}
catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {}
```

I suspect that I have decoded the modulus string incorrectly, because generating the public key in Android encrypts the key successfully.  I used this code:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");     
kpg.initialize(1024);     
KeyPair kpa = kpg.genKeyPair();     
pubKey = kpa.getPublic();
```

So, what have I done wrong?

Comment: You do understand that transfering a security key like this, over unencrypted traffic, means anyone can pick it up right? Are you using the Mono for Android, we need more information, if we are to help you.

Comment: To clarify: I'm using Java / Eclipse for Android. The security key isn't being sent unencrypted.  The RSA public key embedded in the Java code is used to encrypt an AES symmetric key.  The encrypted AES key is sent to the server, which decrypts it with its (secret) RSA private key and is used to encrypt the server's response to the Android client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `new BigInteger(1, modulus)`. BigIntegers are signed and as the modulus starts with the first bit set to 1, it will always be interpreted as a negative number.

Comment: You can only store a negative amount of data within a negative modulus :)

Comment: `BigInteger(1, modulus)` has solved the problem.  You've saved the day, many thanks.