# How to use RSAPrivate Key generated by C# in java/ Android?

Tags: java, c#, android, rsa

My server side(C# or .Net) people giving me a RSA Key pair in **xml** format, but the problem is I am not able to use given keys in my **Java/ Android** code and it always throwing **InValidKeySpec** exception.

Somehow I managed RSAPublic key conversion into Java understandable RSAPublic key format like this way -

```
String Modoutput = "pgFkNu7tN3K8VCxxvKMFwqaRJ6I158/aihg1J1p13P5HvVz8Pn2oC7hfdhujlQxHPsV/b8Rc3Snq5KGmC4VBnw==";
            String Expoutput = "AQAB";

            byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.decode(Expoutput);
            byte[] modulusBytes =  Base64.decode(Modoutput);

            BigInteger e = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);
            BigInteger m = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
            RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
            PublicKey mServerPublicKey = rsaKeyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

But not able to convert given **RSAPrivate (C#)** key into **Java/ Android** understandable. 
I tried this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6623/Porting-Java-Public-Key-Hash-to-C-NET), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178700/exporting-rsa-key-object-to-xml-in-java)

I am looking into this but not getting any success, need help from the experts.

Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the private exponent in your XML, this is the equivalent code for generating the private key in Java. For Android replace the base64 encoding part

```
String privateExponentB64 = "...";
String modulusB64 = "...";

byte[] privateExponentBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateExponentB64);
byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(modulusB64);

BigInteger privateExponent = new BigInteger(1, privateExponentBytes);
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
RSAPrivateKeySpec privateKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, privateExponen);
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PrivateKey privateKey = factory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
```

Comment: <Modulus> and <Exponent> is okay but what about other part like <P>, <Q>, <DP>, <DQ>, <InverseQ>, <D> ?? are those not necessary to generate a Java understandable Private key??

Comment: the *privateExponent* (not the public) and the modulus are enough to create the key. Use <D> value for the privateExponent

Comment: when I am trying to use this private key, getting BadPaddingexception

Comment: The error may be due to many reasons, which may have nothing to do with the code I have provided. Please update your question or create a new one with the code you are using to  use the private key, as well as the complete trace of the error

Answer (score -1):

you may take a reference from this link

[How do I use a C# generated RSA public key in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981432/how-do-i-use-a-c-sharp-generated-rsa-public-key-in-android)

as it seems it will be helpful to you

Comment: Public key is okay, but the problem is I want Private Key as well.

Comment: if you want to convert given key to understandable form    ...... hope this will help you...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214966/convert-java-security-keypair-to-net-rsacryptoserviceprovider

Comment: Please do not post a link as an answer. Include here the relevant parts. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers